# How to update the table as per check-box checked and unchecked in the user list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can any one suggest me how I can update the contact list

Actually i have to update the user in my network like i have the network list which containing users when user is add to network it will checked so if i want to remove i will unchecked and submit then table should update the concept of adding the user is working fine but removing the user is not working.below is my jquery code:

```
$modelPopup.find('#form-add-email').on('submit', function(){

    var $form = $(this),
    $selUsers = $listUsers.filter(':checked');

    // validate form to select at least one user.
    if($selUsers.length == 0){
        alert("Please select at least one user");
        return false;
    }

    // post data.
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        error: function(jq,status,message) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $msg ="<p class='msg msg_unsuccess'>"+ 'A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message + '</p>';
            $('.msg_wrapper').html($msg);
            $('.msg_wrapper p.msg').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        if (response.success==true) {

            var msg = "<p class='msg msg_success'>"+response.errors+"</p>";
            $modelPopup.find('.close').click();
            $('.msg_wrapper').html(msg);
        }
        if (response.success==false) {
            var msg = "<p class='msg msg_unsuccess'>"+response.errors+"</p>";
            $('#share_via_mail .msg_wrapper').html(msg);
            $('.msg_wrapper').html(msg);
        }
        $('.msg_wrapper p.msg').delay(3000).fadeOut();
        $('.btn').removeClass('no_loader');
            $('.reset_loader').addClass('no_loader');
    });

    return false;
});
```

This is my scenario so please help me out how i will achieve it.

Comment: what error showing in your console ?

Comment: no error,it is not working for unchecked functionality

Comment: you should setup common class name to all checkbox and call like this $(document).on('click','.class_name',function(){   });

Comment: @jothi Class name is same   <input id="user{{$count}}" <?php echo $checked; ?> class="share_checkbox share-user-checkbox" name="users[]" type="checkbox"  value="{{$user->id}}" />